# Magnetization at high temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

What is the physical mechism that disorders magnetic alignment and prevents the material from magnetizing?

I believe that thermal fluctuations are responsable but I don't understand what a thermal fluctuation is in spin systems. What force acts on the spins in orden to flip them against the external field?

Comment: This website has a 168 page pdf, which from my limited knowledge,  I think might help you. The lower r.h.s has a button with three dots, which produces a slider. My apologies if I am way off on what you want. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3066537/

Comment: pl. specify  the temperature range....above or below curie temperature as the theoretical model changes to explain the magnetization.